# Why is Finder adding .app extension to .service file?

Tags: finder, file-extensions

Reproduce:

```
$ nano example.service  # (add some text to file and save)
$ ls example.service
example.service
```

Looks good so far.

What's this?

[image]

Comment: wouldn't `example.workflow` be usable ?

Comment: I'm creating service files to upload eventually to Ubuntu server.

Comment: I think the legacy `service` thing in automator has been replaced by `application` .

Comment: That's fine, I don't care how OSX automates tasks. I just don't understand why the finder apparently renames the file, but the extra `.app` extension isn't visible in the terminal -- so I assume the *actual* file name does not have the `.app` extension.